# Script to delete pages with jsp in AEM 6.4

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, aem, crx

Please I need a script to delete pages with JSP in AEM.
For example, I can do it on  cURL with this script,
curl -u admin:admin -X DELETE "http://localhost:4502/content/hostdesign24/en/page[1-3]"
[page deleted with curl script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce24N.png)

I just need to the same script in JSP
thanks

Comment: So I would suggest you read some documentation and try on your own and if you should fail, you can come back here and tell us what the problem is. SO is not about telling other people to do your work...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `PageManager`, specifically to the `delete` methods. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageManager.html